# Finding the angle $\angle BDC$

Tags: geometry

[image]

Let's assume that $\angle DBC = 50^{\circ}$, $[DC]$ bisects $\angle ACB$, and that $|AC| = |BC|-|AD|$. How could we find the angle $\angle BDC$?

Applying angle bisector theorem:

$$\frac{|AD|}{|BD|} = \frac{|AC|}{|BC|}$$

Since $|AC| = |BC|-|AD|$,

$$\frac{|AD|}{|BD|} = \frac{|BC|-|AD|}{|BC|} = 1-\frac{|AD|}{|BC|}$$

$$|AD|\biggr(\frac{1}{|BD|}+\frac{1}{|BC|}\biggr) = 1$$

But this won't lead me anywhere, I believe. Could we take complex geometric approach to this problem?

Comment: Is $DC$ bisecting $\angle ACB$ part of the problem statement?

Comment: Yes, it is part of the problem statement.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the full problem statement?

Comment: I just edited the problem statement.

Comment: Anything I can see using vector methods (or complex numbers) is far more complicated than the two synthetic approaches that have been suggested.

Comment: Sure, thanks for your so valuable thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

A fairly simple problem. Though you ask for a method that involved the complex plane, I'll share a method relying purely on Euclidean Geometry as how you originally seemed to have attempted this question.

[image]

1.) Since we know that $AC=BC-AD$, we can rewrite this as $BC=AC+AD$. Now, for our ease, we shall label $AC=a$ and $AD=b$, this implies that $AC=a+b$. (We can also label the bisected angles as $\alpha$)

2.) Locate $E$ outside $\triangle ABC$ such that $AE=b$. Also join $B$ and $E$ via $BE$, and $D$ and $E$ via $DE$. This construction shows that $AE=AC=a+b$, therefore, $\triangle ABE$ is an isosceles triangle. Since $DC$ is an angle bisector of $\angle ACB$, we can extend $DC$ to meet $BE$ at point $F$. It is easy to see that, because $\triangle ABE$ is isosceles, that segment $CF$ is both the perpendicular and angle bisector of $\triangle ABE$

3.) Notice that, via the SAS property, $\triangle CBD$ and $\triangle CED$ are congruent. This implies that $BD=DE$ and $\angle CBD=\angle CED=50^\circ$. Via some basic angle chasing, it is easy to show that $\angle DBF=\angle DEF=40-\alpha$. This means that, via the exterior angle property, $\angle EDA=80-2\alpha$. However, we already know that $AD=b$ and $AE=b$, thus, $\angle EDA=\angle DEA=50$. This means that:

$$80-2\alpha=50$$

$$\alpha=15$$

Therefore, $\angle BDC=180-65=115$

Comment: Sure, but out of pure curiosity, is it possible to use complex geometry here, in this problem? Would it make things any simpler? To be honest, I'm not very good at synthetic approach.

Comment: @Melz Yes it is, there are multiple ways to solve this problem using complex geometry. That said, I doubt it'll make things any simpler. Often, a geometrical or trigonometric solution for such problems is as simple as you may get, and it is also accessible to a wider audience who may not be familiar with complex geometry as we are

Comment: Thanks for your so valuable thoughts!

Comment: Are there some typos in the pic?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = ∠BCD \;,\; y = ∠BDC$

We are only concerned with angles. Let $|CD|=1$

$|BC| = |AC| + |AD|$

$\displaystyle \require{cancel}\frac{\sin(y)}{\sin 50°} 
= \frac{\sin(y) }{\sin(y-x)}
+ \frac{\sin(x) }{\sin(y-x)}
= \frac{\cancel{2} \sin(\frac{y+x}{2})\cancel{\cos(\frac{y-x}{2})}}
{\cancel{2} \sin(\frac{y-x}{2}) \cancel{\cos(\frac{y-x}{2})}}$

$ x + y = 180°-50° = 130°$

$\displaystyle \require{cancel}\frac{\sin(y)}{\sin 50°} 
= \frac{\sin 65°}{\sin(y-65°)}
= \frac{\sin 115°}{\sin(y-65°)}
$

$→ y = 115°$

---

We can also solve directly for y, by cross multiply.

$\sin(y)\;\sin(y-65°) = -\frac{1}{2} \big(\cos(2y-65°) - \cos(65°)\;\big)$

$\sin(115°)\;\;\sin(50°) = -\frac{1}{2} \big(\;\;\cos(165°) \quad - \cos(65°)\;\big)$

$\cos(2y-65°) = \cos(165°)$

$\require{cancel} → y = 115°, \cancel{130°}\qquad
$// 2nd solution implied $x=0°$, thus not valid

Comment: Geometric solution is most elegant, too bad it is taken. ∠A = 2*∠B --> x = (180°-∠A-∠B)/2 = 15°

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the point on $[BC]$ for which $XC = AC$.

Note: this is the main move -- idea behind this being just that it "feels right" in a way that it seems like it could be a way to use the $AD + AC = BC$ information.

$\Delta XCD$ and $\Delta ACD$ are congruent triangles by SAS. So then $XD = AD$.

But $BX = BC - XC = BC - AC = AD = XD$.

Then $\Delta BXD$ is isosceles. And so $\angle BDX = 50^{\circ}$. And because $\Delta XCD$ and $\Delta ACD$ are congruent, $\angle XDC = \angle ADC = 65^{\circ}$. And so $\angle BDC = 115^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\displaystyle x = \frac{∠A}{2} \;,\; y = \frac{∠C}{2}\;$

Given $∠B=50° \quad → 2x+2y = 130°$

**Law of Tangent, on ΔACD**, given $AD = (a-b)$

$\displaystyle \frac{b-(a-b)}{b+(a-b)} 
= \frac{2b}{a} - 1
= \frac{\tan \left(\frac{(180-2x-y)-y}{2}\right)}{\tan \left(\frac{(180-2x-y)+y}{2}\right)}
= \frac{\tan 25°}{\tan (90°-x)}
= (\tan 25°)(\tan x)
$

**Law of Sine, on on ΔABC**

$\displaystyle \frac{b}{a} = \frac{\sin 50°}{\sin 2x}$

Let $t_1 = \tan 25° \;,\; t_2 = \tan x\;$, combine the two expressions:

$\displaystyle
2 \left(\frac{2t_1}{1+t_1^2} \right)
÷ \left(\frac{2t_2}{1+t_2^2} \right) - 1 = t_1\,t_2 $

$\displaystyle → t_2 = \frac{1}{t_1} \;\lor\; \frac{2\,t_1}{1-t_1^2} = \tan(65°) \;\lor\; \tan(50°)$

$x=65° ⇒ ∠C = 0°$, not a triangle, thus not a solution.

$x=50° ⇒ ∠C = 30° ⇒ ∠BDC = \left(180 - 50 - \frac{30}{2}\right)\!° = 115°\;$

---

Perhaps simpler way to solve for x:

$\displaystyle 2\left(\frac{\sin 50°}{\sin 2x}\right) 
= 1 + (\tan25°)(\tan x)
= \frac{(\cos 25°)(\cos x) + (\sin 25°)(\sin x)}{(\cos 25°)(\cos x)}$

$\displaystyle \require{cancel} \frac{\sin 50°}{(\sin x)\cancel{(\cos x)}}
= \frac{\cos(x-25°)}{(\cos 25°){\cancel{(\cos x)}}}$

$(\sin 50°)(\cos 25°) = \sin(x)\cos (x-25°) \quad → x=50°$

Comment: How to strike-out cos(x) on both side?

Comment: I think its obvious they'll 'cancel' so there's need to strike it out @albertchan

Comment: I just want to learn how to do this in Latex.  I figured this out :)

Answer (score 0):

Law of Sines works nice. We know the following three facts.

$$\frac{\sin(50+x)}{|AC|}=\frac{\sin(x)}{|AD|}$$

$$\frac{\sin(130-2x)}{|BC|}=\frac{\sin(2x)}{|AD|+|BD|}$$ $$\frac{\sin(x)}{|BD|}=\frac{\sin(130-x)}{|BC|}$$ These three equations imply that   $$\frac{|AC|}{|AD|}=\frac{\sin(50+x)}{\sin(x)}$$ $$\frac{|AD|}{|BC|}=\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin(130-2x)}-\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(130-x)}$$ It follows that $$\frac{\sin\left(50+x\right)}{\sin\left(x\right)}-\left(\frac{1}{\frac{\sin\left(2x\right)}{\sin\left(130-2x\right)}-\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{\sin\left(130-x\right)}}\right)=\frac{|AC|}{|AD|}-\frac{|BC|}{|AD|}=-1$$ The above implies $x=15^{\circ}$ and the angle measure you seek is $130-x=115^{\circ}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $2\alpha=\angle ACB$. Then the law of sines in $\triangle ADC$ and $\triangle ABC$ gives respectively
$$\frac{AD}{AC}=\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin(\alpha +50^\circ)}$$
$$\frac{BC}{AC}=\frac{\sin(2\alpha+50^\circ)}{\sin50^\circ}$$
Since $\frac{BC}{AC}=\frac{AD+AC}{AC}=\frac{AD}{AC}+1$ we get

$$\frac{\sin(2\alpha+50^\circ)}{\sin50^\circ}=\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin(\alpha +50^\circ)}+1$$

Thanks to Albert Chan's comment, we can see that $\alpha= 15^\circ$ and thus $\angle BDC= 115^\circ.$

Comment: Just move 1 to LHS, as sin(50°)/sin(50°) --> 2*cos(x+50°)*sin(x)/sin(50°) = sin(x)/sin(x+50°) --> sin(2x+100°) = sin(50°) = sin(130°) --> x = 15°

Comment: Thanks @albertchan